# Adding value to the additional attribute of product via SOAP V1

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v1

I have created one additional attribute with dropdown field. When i add values via SOAP v1, i could not be able to add.

following is my code

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], 'testSKU',array(
    'categories' => array(0,1),
    'name' => 'Test Product',
    'description' => 'Description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 2,
    'meta_title' => 'MetaTitle',
    'meta_keyword' => 'MetaKeyword',
    'meta_description' => 'MetaDesc',
    'brand' => 'brand')));
```

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960692/how-do-i-create-a-product-with-additional-attributes-in-magento-via-soap-java/10608275#10608275

Comment: @osrecio This is for V2. I need it for V1

Answer (score 0):

Add `'custom_attr' => 'value'` inside your product array directly instead of adding it separately as additional attributes.
This will solve your problem for V1.